# Android - How kill process with ppid = 1

Tags: android, linux, bash, pppd

I'm in an android project that performs communication through a satellite modem.

You need to run the pppd command for the modem to make the connection via android.

I performed this command through a bash.

```
   process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "root", "-c", "/data/local/android_connect.sh", "&> /mnt/sdcard/Download/log.txt"});
```

In some moments the android creates this process with PPID = 1

When this happens I can not kill the process by executing the following command

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pidProcess);
        if (process != null)
            process.destroy();
```

Is it possible to kill a process with PPID = 1 through android?

Comment: Why don't you kill by the PID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea, but you can try to call
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + PID);`.
Or try to call `killBackgroundProcesses` instead of `killProcess`. `killProcess` does not allow you to kill processes with UID that differs from your app UID, while `killBackgroundProcesses` can do that for you.

And be sure, that your app have permissions like `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER`, `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` and `android.permission.GET_TASKS`.

Comment: Perhaps `-9` is not necessary. The fact that the parent process is `init` should make no difference, should it?

Comment: Yes, I think it should make really no difference. But if author have problems with terminating proc - I thing SIGKILL could help.

Comment: What's the difference between **killBackgroundProcess**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I've fixed me reply. I've meant killBackgroundProcess**es**. It allows you to kill processes with UID that differs from your application while **killProcess** can terminate only processes with same UID as your app.

Answer (score 1):

The `PID=1` is the process manager. It's executed directly after the kernel and if you kill it all the processes will die. It's not recommended to so it, but if you're decided you could try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + PID);
```

Comment: Does garbage collection still take place after this call?